# What is the best way to convert between char* and System::String in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, string, c++-cli

What is the approved way to convert from char* to System::string and back in C++/CLI? I found a few references to marshal_to<> templated functions on Google, but it appears that this feature never made the cut for Visual Studio 2005 (and isn't in Visual Studio 2008 either, AFAIK). I have also seen some code on [Stan Lippman's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/slippman/archive/2004/06/02/147090.aspx), but it's from 2004. I have also seen Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(). Is there a method that is considered "best practice"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a good overview here (this marshaling support added for VS2008):
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/OrcasMarshalAs.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but that is a lengthy explanation. This goes more to the point: `#include <msclr\marshal.h> // marshal_context context; //
my_c_string = context.marshal_as<const char*>(my_csharp_string);`

Comment: For those who wonder, the full namespace for context is `msclr::interop::marshal_context`

Answer (score 80):

System::String has a constructor that takes a char*:

```
 using namespace system;
 const char* charstr = "Hello, world!";
 String^ clistr = gcnew String(charstr);
 Console::WriteLine(clistr);
```

Getting a char* back is a bit harder, but not too bad:

```
 IntPtr p = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(clistr);
 char *pNewCharStr = static_cast<char*>(p.ToPointer());
 cout << pNewCharStr << endl;
 Marshal::FreeHGlobal(p);
```

Comment: +1, System::String constructor also takes length and encoding!

Comment: `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi` is a poor option compared to `marshal_context` (as mentioned by Matthew), which uses RAII to automatically free the buffer.  Not to mention that the name is totally wrong, it doesn't return an `HGLOBAL` at all.

Comment: Your example does not work for me in C++/CLI using .NET 4.6.1. There is no System::String constructor that takes a char*... only signed char* or wchar_t*

Comment: It's been a while since I've been in this world, but I believe this should still work. According to the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/string-cpp-component-extensions, you should still be able to `gcnew` a string with a `char *` string as the argument. Maybe you can cast to `signed char *`?

Comment: From my experience the pointer also has no nul terminator. You need to use clistr.Length to know how long it is.

Answer (score 0):

What we did is made a C++\CLI object that held the string in unmangaed code and would give out manged copies of the item.  The conversion code looks very much like what Stan has on his blog (I can't remember it exactly)(If you use his code make sure you update it to use delete[]) but we made sure that the destructor would handle releasing all the unmanged elements of the object.  This is a little overblown but we didn't have leaks when we tied into legacy C++ code modules.

Answer (score 0):

I created a few helper methods. I needed to do this to move from an old Qt library to CLI String. If anyone can add onto this and tell me if it seems like I have a memory leak and what I can do to fix it, I would be most appreciative.

```
void MarshalString (  String ^ s, wstring& os ) {
    using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
    const wchar_t* char = (const wchar_t*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(s)).ToPointer();
    os = char;
}
QString SystemStringToQt( System::String^ str)
{
    wstring t;
    MarshalString(str, t);
    QString r = QString::fromUcs2((const ushort*)t.c_str());
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Probably have to Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars)); it

Comment: @Pat yes sorry I should have updated this after this. I did get it working well now. Moving it to .NET increased the performance of this app by 3x. Even marshaling things around.

Answer (score -1):

One additional link to a summary of possible ways:

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=311259