# How do I convert a System::String to a unsigned char *?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

I saw [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-between-char-and-systemstring-in-c-cli) that suggested the following:

```
String^ clistr = gcnew String("sample");
IntPtr p = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(clistr);
char *pNewCharStr = static_cast<char*>(p.ToPointer());
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(p);
```

I just wanted to check and see if there is any other, preferred way, or if anything was wrong with the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first result on google for  "System::String char*" seems to offer pretty comprehensive guidance.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311259