# How to convert char * to a System::string ^

Tags: string, c++-cli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to convert between char* and System::String in C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-between-char-and-systemstring-in-c-cli)

Hello,
I have a  function in a c++ project using \clr something like:

```
int WINAPI dmtTest(char *pcertificate) 
{    
    String^ sCertificate;    
    sCertificate = pcertificate; // how can I assign pcertificate to sCertificate?
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do:

```
String^ sCertificate;
sCertificate = gcnew String(pcertificate);
```

Comment: This works... trying to find the opposite direction (String to Char*)...