# Initialise System::String^ with literal but not string::c_str() or char[]

Tags: c++, .net, string, c++-cli, console.writeline

I've recently started learning about .net and the Windows API and I'm currently writting a class which talks the serial port.

In order to write a line to the serial port, I use the `WriteLine` function which takes a parameter, `System::String^`.  I would like to know if it is possible to initialise the `System::String^` from a `std::string`.

I've noticed that I can do the following:

```
serialPort->WriteLine("stuff");
```

but I cannot do:

```
std::string data = "stuff";
serialPort->WriteLine(data.c_str());
```

also, I cannot do:

```
char data[] = "stuff";
serialPort->WriteLine(data);
```

nor

```
char* data = "stuff";
serialPort->WriteLine(data);
```

Could someone let me know what's going on here?  Is VS somehow converting the literal to it's own thing when I pass it in?

Lastly, I'm not sure if I've selected the correct tags for this as I don't really know what this falls under.

Comment: You're trying to mix the .NET stuff with C and C++ stuff, which doesn't always come out so well. The .NET `String` type is *not* the same thing as `std::string` or a `char` array, and they're not inter-convertible. You should use whichever type is expected by the functions that you're calling.

Comment: Can you do `const char data[] = "stuff"; WriteLine(data)`?

Comment: Have you tried constructing a System::String^ with the data.c_str() using gcnew?

[This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/56779/77915) would likely work (replace the const char* with a std::string and c_str() as needed).

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always call functions with string literals because the compiler automatically converts that to a value of the appropriate string type.

The problem here is that you're trying to mix the .NET Framework stuff (`System::String`) with the standard C++ string type (`std::string`), and they simply don't mix well. The .NET functions that accept a parameter of type `System::String` are *not* written or overloaded to accept a parameter of type `std::string`. If you're working with the .NET Framework, then you're using C++/CLI, and you're generally expected to use the .NET string type, not the C++ string type.

Analogously, standard C++ functions are expecting `std::string` and don't know anything about the .NET Framework string type. So if you're expecting to call functions from the C++ standard library, you should be using its string type.

C-style strings (`char[]`) are the old fallback, not something you really ever want to use when writing C++ code. `std::string` is always a better option, and it even provides the `c_str()` method that you already know about to use when calling an API function that expects a char array. But like the other two string types, this one isn't inter-convertible either.

One particularly large problem that you'll run into is that `std::string` and `char[]` types accept only "narrow" (non-Unicode) strings, whereas the .NET Framework `System::String` type works only with wide (Unicode) strings. That throws a further wrench in the mix when it comes to conversion. There's no way it can be as simple as a cast.

But that doesn't mean it's impossible to convert between the types. There's a helpful document on MSDN that explains [how to convert between various C++ string types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx).

In summary, you can convert from C-style strings to `System::String` by using the appropriately overloaded constructor that accepts a `char*`:

```
const char* cString = "Hello, World!";
System::String ^netString = gcnew System::String(cString);
Console::WriteLine(netString);
delete netString;
```

And then, of course, you can convert from to `std::string` to `System::String` by combining the above method with the `c_str()` method:

```
std::string stdString("Hello, World!");
System::String ^netString = gcnew System::String(stdString.c_str());
Console::WriteLine(netString);
delete netString;
```