# C++ /cli Convert LPCSTR to System::String^

Tags: c++, string, c++-cli, marshalling, lpcstr

I'm having a problem with converting LPCSTR to System::String^, though i am able to convert System::String to LPCSTR with Marshal.

But how can i convert LPCSTR to System::String^

Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to convert between char* and System::String in C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-between-char-and-systemstring-in-c-cli)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
gcnew System::String(lpcstrThing);
```

Comment: Actually, yes. Do you really want complexities in such a simple operation ?

Comment: The `String` class has a constructor that accepts `char*` input, which copies the data up to the first null character it finds. If the data is not null-terminated, or if you know the data length ahead of time, you can use a different constructor: `gcnew System::String(lpcstrThing, 0, length);`
`