# how to transfer contents of char[] to a String^ in C++/CLI

Tags: string, c++-cli, string-concatenation, char-pointer

I've commandLine arguments in a C++/CLI program denoted by char* argv[]. 
I want to transfer all the contents getting concatenated to a String^ class.

Code:

```
String ^masterString = "Commands=>";

for(int i=0; argv[i] != nullptr; ++i)
masterString += String(argv[i]);
```

However, I find the above not working in the last statement where I use `+=` operator.

1. What's the wrong usage here? Error here is No operators match the operands.
2. Any other better ways to store contents into String^ from char*?

Comment: `String` is a Java class, in C++ it's `std::string`. What error are you getting ?

Comment: You should stop when `i >= argc`

Comment: This is wrong `for(int i=0; argv[i] != nullptr; ++i)` should be `for(int i=0; i < argc; ++i)`

Comment: I've fixed the question, that's definitely a C++/CLI and not C++.

Comment: I approved your edit, m0nhawk

Comment: Can anyone pl help? looks like an answer proposed is deleted below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to convert between char\* and System::String in C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-between-char-and-systemstring-in-c-cli)

Answer (score 0):

Look into [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx), mostly into [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859.aspx):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;

int main() {
   const char* message = "Test String to Marshal";
   String^ result;
   result = marshal_as<String^>( message );
   return 0;
}
```

*btw*: I didn't check this. Just googled it. But, I think, this would work, cause it posted in MSDN.