# Conversion of Char array to String in Managed C++

Tags: c#, string, dll, managed-c++

I am making a library application in Managed c++. In that Application i have one character array. I am using the dll of this application in C#. In one of the method of this dll i want to return value as string. In that method i am trying to convert  character array to string. But i am not able to achieve this. Please help me.
 I have character array as

```
array<char>^ montype =gcnew array<char>(14);
```

The method is as

```
String ^ ClassName:: GetMonType()
{
    return montype->ToString();
}
```

In c# i am  having code as

```
string montype = ClassNameObject.GetMonType().ToString();
```

But i am getting value of montye as `Sytem.SByte[]` . I am not getting the value which  i have passed from that library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to convert between char* and System::String in C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-between-char-and-systemstring-in-c-cli)

Comment: Is the String constructor not sufficient for this?

Comment: You probably want to use `System.Char` and not `char`. The latter being a native type.

Comment: I have used System::Char but still i have same problem.

Comment: @Dany: Call the String constructor passing the array as the only parameter. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string.aspx

Comment: I tried to pass character array to the constructor of System::String but i am getting error as "error c2440 cannot convert from system.string to System::String ^"

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got answer .
I modified array as

```
array<System::Char>^ montype =gcnew array<System::Char>(14);
```

and after that i returned value as

```
Sytem::String ^ ClassName:: GetMonType()
    {
       String returnValue = gcnew String(montype );
        return returnValue ;
    }
```

And now its working finely.