# Converting char-array to System::String^

Tags: .net, string, char, c++-cli

As part of my code, I need to output in a textBox a string of 8 characters that have been encrypted. So I need to transform an array of 8 characters to System `String^`. I tried the following:

```
char result[8];
for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    result[i] = (char)DecimalCypher[7-i];
}

textBox3->Text = gcnew String(result);
```

However, the textBox is showing more than 8 characters. 8 characters will change depending on the input, and the remaining will stay as is. 
Example,
If my input is

> andrew12

, the output in the textBox is

> T)W+"Ziz**BVÎ pé**

However if my input is

> andrew33 , the output will be : 
>   A1-1`+Ta**BVÎ pé**

The last 6 characters are the same.. but should not be here in the first place.
It is the first 8 characters that matter!

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: You need to marshal the unmanaged string into the managed string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx

Comment: change `char result[8];` to `char result[9] ={0};`

Comment: Thou shall null terminate all c-style strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to convert between char\* and System::String in C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-between-char-and-systemstring-in-c-cli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When filling up a char array with the intent to use it as a string, always make sure the byte after the last valid byte is a null. More here: [What is a 'Null Terminated String' ?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181505/what-is-a-null-terminated-string)

```
char result[8];
```

Makes variable `result` and allocates space for 8 characters.

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    result[i] = (char)DecimalCypher[7-i];
}
```

fills up all 8 characters in `result`.

```
textBox3->Text = gcnew String(result);
```

Makes an new String `result` as though `result` was a c-style string. Unfortunately `result` is not a c-style string because it has not been null terminated.

Instead use:

```
char result[9];
```

Makes variable `result` and allocates space for 9 characters.

```
result[8] = '\0';
```

null terminates `result`.

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    result[i] = (char)DecimalCypher[7-i];
}
```

Fills up 8 characters in `result`. The 9th is used by the null.

```
textBox3->Text = gcnew String(result);
```

Makes an new String with c-style string `result`